# ¿Cómo mostrar todas las péliculas que me devuelve la Api?

Tags: api, reactjs, map, graphql

Usando graphql y [react](https://es.reactjs.org/) he creado una web para mostrar películas usando la api de The Movie Database Api. El Problema es que solo me renderiza una sola película. Antes del render si que mediante los console.log me muestra mas de una película el problema es que no soy capaz de hacer que renderice mas de una película. ¿Cómo podría sacar todas al menos 10 películas por componente?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Estrenos extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    movie: this.estrenos()
    };
    console.log('Constructor')



 this.estrenos = this.estrenos.bind(this);
  }
  async estrenos() { 
    console.log('entra')     
    const movieData = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/graphql/?query={
        Estrenos{
          id
          posterPath
          title
          overview
          voteAverage
        }  
    }`
    )
    console.log(movieData.data.data.Estrenos[0].id)
    return await this.setState({ movie: movieData.data.data.Estrenos[0]});
  }       
  render() {    
    return (             
      <table className="tablapeliculas" key={this.state.movie.id}>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
            <img
                  className="poster"
                  alt="poster"
                  src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${this.state.movie.posterPath}`}
                />
            </td>
            <td className="combitextos">
              <h3 className="titulosPeliculas">{this.state.movie.title}</h3>
              <p className="textosPeliculas">{this.state.movie.overview}</p>
              <h2 className="valoracionPeliculas">
                {this.state.movie.voteAverage} / 10
              </h2>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );    


  } 

  }


export default Estrenos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si `this.state.movies` es una lista de películas tienes que recorrerlas con la función `.map`, sería algo así.

```
render() {
  ...
  {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
    <tr key={movie.id}>
            <td>
            <img
                  className="poster"
                  alt="poster"
                  src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.posterPath}`}
                />
            </td>
            <td className="combitextos">
              <h3 className="titulosPeliculas">{movie.title}</h3>
              <p className="textosPeliculas">{movie.overview}</p>
              <h2 className="valoracionPeliculas">
                {movie.voteAverage} / 10
              </h2>
            </td>
          </tr>  
  )}
}
```

De ésta manera obtienes en `movie` cada uno de los items de la lista con sus correspondientes propiedades.

P.D. No tienes que devolver `this.setState...` y menos aún poner await en un return.

Más bien tu clase debería ser algo así:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Estrenos extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movie: this.estrenos()
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() { 
    const movieData = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/graphql/?query={
        Estrenos{
          id
          posterPath
          title
          overview
          voteAverage
        }  
    }`
    )
    this.setState({ movie: movieData.data.data.Estrenos[0]});
  }  

  render() {    
    return (             
      <table className="tablapeliculas" key={this.state.movie.id}>
        <tbody>

          {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
    <tr key={movie.id}>
            <td>
            <img
                  className="poster"
                  alt="poster"
                  src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.posterPath}`}
                />
            </td>
            <td className="combitextos">
              <h3 className="titulosPeliculas">{movie.title}</h3>
              <p className="textosPeliculas">{movie.overview}</p>
              <h2 className="valoracionPeliculas">
                {movie.voteAverage} / 10
              </h2>
            </td>
          </tr>  
  )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );    


  } 

  }


export default Estrenos;
```